# Is this a correct simplification of a circuit like this?

Tags: thevenin, diagram, norton

[image]

I am trying to find the Norton equivalent current of the circuit in the top left but if i simplify the circuit like this i get the wrong answer. I drew the steps i took in simplyfying the resistance, can anyone tell me if the steps are correct?

thank you in advance

Comment: Hello at EE.SE. For greetings and thanks, please see [Expected Behaviour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am trying to find the Norton equivalent current of the circuit in
> the top left but if i simplify the circuit like this i get the wrong
> answer.*

You're going about this incorrectly. You are trying to find the Norton equivalent circuit between node A and node B and not how the voltage source is loaded when A and B are shorted: -

[image]

So, the Norton equivalent is a current generator in parallel with a resistor. If the question asked for the Thevenin equivalent it would be a resistor in series with a voltage source.

**Solution**

The equivalent resistance looking into node A and B is \$R_3 + R_2||R_4\$. You should notice that \$R_1\$ does not play any role in the answer and, I'll leave that for you to think about. So, you now have a voltage source, \$V\$ in series with an equivalent resistance (Thevenin). Are you able to convert this to the equivalent Norton circuit?